# Extracting bundles of comic book series and issues from a string of text in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string of text that includes a bundle of comic series and issues all in one long block for each row.

Examples are the following:

**Example 1**

"Batman #323, 325, 335, 340, 368-369, 397-400, Amazing Spider-Man #13-17"

**Example 2**

"Amazing Spider-Man #nn, Amazing Spider-Man Annual #10, Amazing Spider-Man 174, 185, 213, 245, 326"

I would like to note that "#nn" should be retained as the series in the comic. If it makes it easier, I can replace the "#nn" with "#00".

I have been trying to use regular expression (or regex) in Python. For instance, I have tried

`r"([a-zA-Z\s\'-]+) #(\d+|\d+-\d+|\w+)"`

The code I have written is as follows

```
import re

def separate_comic_books(comic_books_str):
    series_issue_dict = {}

    # Define a regular expression pattern to extract series and issue information
    pattern = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z\s\'-]+) #(\d+|\d+-\d+|\w+)')

    # Split the string into individual comic book entries
    comic_books_list = re.split(',\s*', comic_books_str)

    # Iterate through the list of comic books
    for comic_book in comic_books_list:
        matches = pattern.findall(comic_book)
        print(matches)

        for match in matches:
            series = match[0].strip()
            issues = match[1].strip()

            # Split the issues if it's a range
            issues_list = [str(i) for i in range(int(issues.split('-')[0]), int(issues.split('-')[-1]) + 1)]

            # Add the comic book to the dictionary based on series
            if series in series_issue_dict:
                series_issue_dict[series].extend(issues_list)
            else:
                series_issue_dict[series] = issues_list

    # Create the final formatted string
    formatted_comic_books = []
    for series, issues in series_issue_dict.items():
        formatted_issues = ', '.join([f"{series} #{issue}" for issue in sorted(issues)])
        formatted_comic_books.append(formatted_issues)

    return ', '.join(formatted_comic_books)

# Provided string of comic books
comic_books_str = "Amazing Spider-Man #nn, Amazing Spider-Man Annual #10, Amazing Spider-Man 174, 185, 213, 245, 326"

result = separate_comic_books(comic_books_str)
print(result)
```

However, I am getting the following results

**Example 1**

```
"Batman #323, Amazing Spider-Man #13"
```

**Example 2**

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nn'
```

However, I would like to get the following results

**Example 1**

```
Batman #323, Batman #325, Batman #335, Batman #340, Batman #368, Batman #369, Batman #397, Batman #398, Batman #399, Batman #400, Amazing Spider-Man #13, Amazing Spider-Man #14, Amazing Spider-Man #15, Amazing Spider-Man #16, Amazing Spider-Man #17
```

**Example 2**

```
Amazing Spider-Man #nn, Amazing Spider-Man Annual #10, Amazing Spider-Man 174, Amazing Spider-Man 185, Amazing Spider-Man 213, Amazing Spider-Man 245, Amazing Spider-Man 326
```

*Is there a way to write a Python code that does this?*

Thank you so much!!

Comment: You seem to be assuming that everything's a range, you need to do something like `if '-' in issues: <split> else: issues_list = issues`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used regex here, just simple split(). The whole class thing might be a bit over kill, but hey I'm also practicing!

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain


class Comics:

    def __init__(self, comic_list: list):
        self.comic_list = comic_list
        self.comic_dictionary = defaultdict(list)
        self._generate_comic_dictionary()

    def _generate_comic_dictionary(self):
        current_title = ''
        for comic in self.comic_list.split(','):
            comic = comic.strip()
            if '#' in comic:
                title, issue = comic.split('#')
                current_title = title
            else:
                issue = comic
            self._add_comics_to_dictionary(current_title, issue)

    def _add_comics_to_dictionary(self, title: str, issue: str):
        title = title.strip()
        issue = issue.strip()
        if '-' in issue:
            start, end = issue.split('-')
            self.comic_dictionary[title].extend([str(i) for i in range(int(start), int(end) + 1)])
        else:
            self.comic_dictionary[title].append(issue)

    def get_comics_dictionary(self):
        return self.comic_dictionary

    def __str__(self):
        return_list = [[title + ' #' + issue for issue in issues] for title, issues in self.comic_dictionary.items()]
        return ', '.join(list(chain(*return_list)))
```

Ouput

```
comics_list = 'Batman #nn, 325, 335, 340, 368-369, 397-400, Amazing Spider-Man #13-17'
comics = Comics(comics_list)
print(comics)
```

```
Batman #nn, Batman #325, Batman #335, Batman #340, Batman #368, Batman #369, Batman #397, Batman #398, Batman #399, Batman #400, Amazing Spider-Man #13, Amazing Spider-Man #14, Amazing Spider-Man #15, Amazing Spider-Man #16, Amazing Spider-Man #17

Process finished with exit code 0
```